# ¿Una pregunta puede depender de otra?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

En el supuesto caso de que existiera una pregunta complicada, para responder es necesario hacer una pregunta más simple.

¿Está bien esperar las respuestas de la pregunta simple y luego responder la complicada con lo aprendido en la simple?

Es decir, ¿Puede una pregunta depender de otra?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ya sea una pregunta o respuesta, en el sitio principal una publicación no puede depender de otra, debe de ser clara, concisa y completa.

Es normal que algunas personas requieran hacer varias preguntas para entender un tema o resolver un problema complejo. Me parece que en lo general es mejor hacer una pregunta a la vez ya que la respuesta a una pregunta podría ser de utilidad para que la siguiente pregunta sea mejor, pero no descarto que para mantener una pregunta enfocada, se puedan realizar varias preguntas de forma simultánea sobre diferentes aspectos particularmente cuando las preguntas no depende de la respuesta a otras preguntas.

Comment: Concuerdo con Rubén y quisiera destacar la diferencia que hay entre "dependencia" y "correlación". Una manera en la que se puede saber si una pregunta depende de otra, es preguntarse "Si dejase de existir la pregunta A... ¿Podría entenderse/responderse la pregunta B?", si la respuesta es sí, entonces la pregunta B depende de la pregunta A.

Comment: Debe. Ser. Autocontenida. Si alguien llega en un momento del futuro y revisa una pregunta que encontró buscando, no tiene como ir a las otras seis donde el OP revisó otros aspectos del mismo problema. "Como les dije en la pregunta anterior" debería quitarle 100 puntos a griffyndor o a hufflepuff, siempre.